# Visualize travelling salesman solution graphically using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphics, visualization, data-visualization

I wrote a ruby script that finds a solution to the Bays29 travelling salesman problem. The bays29 data set is found here:
http://elib.zib.de/pub/mp-testdata/tsp/tsplib/tsp/bays29.tsp

Now say my solution is in an array that says go to city 1, then 4, then 9 etc.. 
I want to show this visually being solved somehow. For e.g. I would like to have it in a browser showing all the cities connected together and then the solution gets highlighted after it is generated.

How can I go about doing this? 
What kind of gems should I use?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Though interesting, I don't think this qualifies as a Stack Overflow question. Please see help centre for more details. Downvote is not mine.

Comment: ahh I agree, this is not a specific programming question. Where is a more appropriate place to ask this?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a small Rails app with the algorithm in a model and some javascript (with either [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/) or [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/)) for map visualization.

The traveling salesman is a hard problem, so it might take a while to calculate a result. You could use [AJAX](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) or [Server Side Events](https://www.rubyplus.com/articles/4081-Server-Side-Event-Streaming-in-Rails-5) to update the map when the server has found a better soluton.

Comment: Ah I didn't know about OpenLayers or Leaflet, seems like they could be helpful. 
Leaflet has an example of an animation as I need. Thanks. 
I will not mark this as an answer until I receive a few other suggestions :)